# How does one Render a texture directly to the Camera in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, textures

In Unity, I have 2 images in the form of a texture that I am merging together (one overlaying the other). I do this in a Compute `Shader` and put the results on a `RenderTexture`. I want this `RenderTexture` to be everything that the output camera sees.

I have found articles saying to use a the `ReplacementShader` property of the camera, but I couldn't get that to properly work.

Currently I have simply put the `RenderTexture` onto a `UIRawImage` that covers the whole UI Canvas so that the entire camera is filled. This however has a lot of lag and is obviously a suboptimal solution.

So how does one output the `Rendertexture` or the compute `Shader` result directly onto the camera. Thanks.

Comment: Did You try to add this texture to UI Image? Should be working fine

Comment: It is also possible that the performance is dropped during the RenderTexture creation process. If you comment out just the part of your code where you assign the RenderTexture to the RawImage, does it actually resolve the performance drop? Because if not, the problem isn't related to RawImage.

Comment: @yasirkula, turned out the lag was actually coming from taking the render texture data between CPU and GPU to use it in a texture2D (as the render texture was relatively large).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could probably use [`OnRenderImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnRenderImage.html)

> Event function that Unity calls after a Camera has finished rendering, that allows you to modify the Camera's final image.

and use [`Graphics.Blit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.Blit.html)

> Copies source texture into destination render texture with a shader.

and do something like e.g.

```c#
// This script goes onto your according Camera
public class RenderReplacement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RenderTexture replacement;

    void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture src, RenderTexture dest)
    {
        // To overwrite the entire screen
        Graphics.Blit(replacement, null);

        // Or to overwrite only what this specific Camera renders
        //Graphics.Blit(replacement, dest);
    }
}
```

Where

> **dest**
>
> The destination `RenderTexture`. Set this to `null` to blit **directly to screen**. See description for more information.

---

Note as mentioned in the API the `OnRenderImage` is called **after** this Camera already finished rendering. So in order to make this more efficient - since we basically throw away that render - simply make sure that camera basically isn't rendering anything by disabling all Layers and e.g. let it only render a single color background

Comment: You example at the end doesn't work, Unity says it's an ambiguous call

Comment: @Sammot cold you add the error you are getting? You probably just need to add the correct `using` directive or explicit namespace in order to refer to [`UnityEngine.Graphics`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.html)